# Not able to push data in empty array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to push data into empty but its returning empty array.
I'm trying push in json format. Push values in rows[]

```
 Result {
      command: 'SELECT',
      rowCount: 2,
      oid: NaN,
      rows:
       [ anonymous { username: 'pewdiepie' },
         anonymous { username: 'tseries' } ],
```

Code:

```
var newList = new Array();

data => {
        for(var  i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
         newList.push(data.rows[i].username)
       }}
```

Comment: It should be `data.rows.length`, not `data.length`.

Comment: Got it thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`i < data.length` should be `i < data.rows.length`. `data` is the container object, `data.rows` is the array you're looping through.

But instead of a loop you can use `map`:

```
newList = data.rows.map(e => e.username);
```

or `forEach`

```
data.rows.forEach(e => newList.push(e.username));
```

Comment: I tried using forEach it didn't work.I don't know why?

Comment: Since I can't see your code, I don't know why either. I've added a `forEach` example to my answer.

Comment: Got my mistake, I didn't use data,rows, I directly went for data.forEach

Comment: That's the same problem you made in your `for` loop, which I pointed out in the first line of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's just one error buddy. The `for` loop should range from `0` to length of `rows` inside the object. But you are doing [object].length. Hence it isn't giving the right output.

Here is the working code:

```js
var data = {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 2,
  oid: NaN,
  rows: [
    anonymous = {
      username: 'pewdiepie'
    },
    anonymous = {
      username: 'tseries'
    }
  ]
}

var newList = new Array();


for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
  newList.push(data.rows[i].username);
}


console.log(newList);
```